# Git - How to selectively clean a repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repo in which, during a build, several artifacts are produced. To make things simple:

- Code generation produces e.g. `.cpp`, `.h` files and maybe some other types of files;
- Build produces .o and .so files
  On top of that, the repo also stores, as tracked files, some other `.cpp`/`.h`/`.o`/`.so` files.

`.gitignore` is configured in such a way that a `git clean -dxf` effectively produces a clean repo.

However, on some occasions, i'd like to clean only build artifacts and keep generated artifacts. Sort of *do a git clean -dxf but only if the file type is .foo*.

I've look into the --exclude option of git clean, but i'm afraid it won't do the job as I only know precisely the types of files that I want to include in the clean, but not the contrary.

For now, the closest I'd have would be something akin to (probably syntactically incorrect, but than gives the idea)

```
find -name "*.so" -or -name "*.os" | xargs -I {} sh -c "git ls-files --error-unmatch {} && rm {}"
```

Did i overlook a git command that would do the job ?

Regards,

Vincent

Comment: As an aside, this is why it is often recommended to do "out of source" builds, so you can just delete the entire directory of generated artifacts, instead of setting up complicated ignore/clean rules for generated files

Comment: @CoryKramer Agreed, but alas I had no say in the matter.

Comment: Note that `git clean` accepts pathspecs with patterns: `git clean -nx` and `git clean -nx "*.ext"` will show you the difference in what would be removed. That might suffice for your particular use case.

Comment: @torek Sometimes the obvious is hard to see ! Thank you, this was precisely what I needed, but somehow didn't think of patterns here. Would you mind formulating a proper answer so I can give you credit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just using `git clean` directly:

> Sort of *do a git clean -dxf but only if the file type is .foo*.

This would be `git clean -dxf -- "*.foo"`.  The `--` is not required here, it's just generally good advice to put pathspecs behind `--` in case a command might otherwise treat them as options.  The double quotes are also not required in *some* cases, but they are in others, and they don't hurt.<sup>1</sup>

(As an aside, `.foo` here is a file *extension* rather than a file *type*, at least on systems where the file's type is determined by something other than its extension.  MacOS gets some negative points here since its Unix underpinnings don't believe in extension-based types, but so many of its apps do. )

---

<sup>1</sup>The exact details depend on your command line interpreter, but apparently this works in `CMD.EXE` at least.  I don't know about PowerShell.  In sh/bash, expressions like `*.foo` will match files—well, files and subdirectories, but directories are in many respects the same as files here—in the *current directory* whose names end with `.foo`, unless they are quoted or there are no such files.  In those two cases, the literal string `*.foo` is passed on to Git, allowing *Git* to expand it in ways that are more appropriate to your task.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and maybe I know how to help you.

I let you here a python3 snippet that I made:

```
 import re
 import subprocess

 def format_output(output, regex=None):
    assert type(output)==list, 'the output parameter need to be a list'

    if not regex:
        output.pop()
        return output

    data = list()
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for line in output:
        match = pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            if pattern.groups > 0:
                set = list()
                for i in range(0, pattern.groups):
                    if match.group(i + 1) is not None:
                        set.append(match.group(i + 1))
                data.append(set)
            else:
                data.append(line)

    return data


def shell_output(command, regex=None):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command)
    lines = output.decode().split('\n')
    return format_output(lines, regex)
```

Using the command find( `shell_output("find")`) you will get a list containing the `splitted find's command output`, adding the `regex parameter` allows you to `filter results.`

You can make a perfect regex to `find only the files that do NOT contain what you want` to include in the clean

Once you find it, close the script with:

```
trash= shell_output("find", *YOURREGEX) 
for stuff in trash  
 os.system("rm"+stuff)
```

And you finally have your Cleaner ;)

Here you will find the `documentation for making your regex`: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

PS: `find` command `work on linux` if you are on windows use a command for recursive directory listing.